# How to know if an account has been blocked?

Tags: discussion

Is there any SQL query written at http://data.stackexchange.com to know if an account (a user) has been blocked / locked on that stack exchange site?

Why I am asking this question?

Because I am very curious about this, also I've been coming to see many user profiles those last seen was like in 2010 or 2011...it means that after that time they want come back.

It may possible that, they are already started using another account, but then my mind asking me, why someone started using another account by leaving good repo and badges?

I want to know

- What happened to their account?
- Is it blocked (locked)?

I've seen that, if some one started another account then their last account get merge with new account, how true it is?

Comment: Idle curiosity really isn't a good reason.

Comment: Or maybe they just needed a problem solved, they had it, and now they don't need help anymore (for any reason). No visits != cannot visit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're assuming that once somebody makes an account here, they're going to continue using the account and continue visiting the site forever.

Your assumption is wrong.

Your questions cannot be answered by a query. They can be answered here however:

> - What happened to their account?

Probably nothing. Who knows?

> - Is it blocked (locked)?

You can see if an account is suspended, but even then, suspensions are temporary. You can't see if a user is blocked from posting questions and/or answers, mostly because the details of those blocks are completely secret.

But the real answer is that an account's last visited date has no correlation with its ability to post or participate whatsoever.